# Why is eclipse installing everything on my C drive?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have limited space on my C drive, hence installing Eclipse in my E drive. After installation I find that about 1mb is on my E drive and all the rest is on my C drive!

Any idea how to get Eclipse to actually install in the folder I want? in previous versions all plugins went into the plugins folder of the install, but it seems Neon wants to install everything into a .p2 folder in my user folder.

Which is pretty useless too if I wanted Eclipse to be available to other users too...

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you downloaded the Windows installer version, which I would avoid if at all possible. While it is possible to tweak your installation to behave as expected, I suggest uninstalling it and downloaded the package of your choice from [Eclipse Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/). Unzip the package on your `E:` drive. The resulting `eclipse` directory will house all current files and plugins and others as you add/download them. The `.p2` directory will still be created in your user directory, but will not contain anything other than some user-specific configuration information.

You can create a shortcut to `eclipse.exe` or on Windows 10 right-click and `Pin to Start` for easy reference. Also make sure that any workspaces you create are created someplace other than your user directory.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. After many years of plugins going wrong with version mismatches, etc I presumed the new 'oomph' version was the only way now (to be honest, I never even noticed the 'download packages' link in light grey at the site that takes you to the page you linked to :)

Comment: Yes, it is sad that they obscure the traditional Download Packages. This isn't the first time, and it would be the last time. In short, I recommend staying away from OS-specific installers for Java applications unless absolutely necessary. There are several other current SO questions related to the new Eclipse installer.